# How to change window title in Qt Creator?

Tags: window, qt-creator

Please tell me How to change window title from `MainWindow` or `Dialog` to other name in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
void    QWidget::setWindowTitle ( const QString & )
```

Also check this [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop)